# How to detect headset wire control in macos

Tags: objective-c, macos

In windows/linux, The headset wire control is the same as the keyboard event. However, I can't use `CGEventSourceKeyState` to detect headset wire control in macos.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of the `MPRemoteCommandCenter` class from the `MediaPlayer` framework, then register for any commands your app supports. However, in order to cooperate with other apps well, you should register as a "Now Playing" app via `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`.

See ["Becoming a Now Playable App"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/becoming_a_now_playable_app) for an example of how to implement this.